# Draw a shape at a known co-ordinate on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt, draw

I have searched quite bit to find a solution to my problem with no luck. I would have thought there to be a simple solution. I have the following code where I find a number of points stored in an ArrayList and would like to drap a shape (Doesn't matter what at this stage, a rectangle will do) at each point given in the ArrayList. The code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        image = null;
        try {
            // Read from a file
            File file = new File("box.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("LAAAAMMME!!!!");
        }

        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(image); //Custom JPanel to show a background image
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Find the Squares");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.validate();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();


        ArrayList<Point> points = getCenterPoint(floatarray);
        for(int x = 0 ; x < points.size(); x++){
             //Here I guess is where each point is created and drawn.
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"*  For better help sooner, upgrade that code to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *//Here I guess is where each point is created and drawn.* Here I guess is where you should do the [2D Graphics Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute `List<Point> list` to `ImagePanel`.

Override `paintComponent(g)` in `ImagePanel`.  Use the data in the attribute `list` to draw.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawRect(...);
}
```

Send the list from `JFrame` to `ImagePanel`.

You might have to call `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout())` after constructing the frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyTest{
public static void main(String[] args){
    image = null;
    try {
        // Read from a file
        File file = new File("box.jpg");
        image = ImageIO.read(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("LAAAAMMME!!!!");
    }

    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(image); //Custom JPanel to show a background image
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Find the Squares");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.add(new MainPanel(Color.Red));
    frame.validate();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    /*ArrayList<Point> points = getCenterPoint(floatarray);
    for(int x = 0 ; x < points.size(); x++){
         //Here I guess is where each point is created and drawn.
    }*/
}
private class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    Color color;

    public MainPanel(Color color) {
       this.color = color;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      int width = getWidth();
      int height = getHeight();
      g.setColor(color);
      //g.drawRect(startx,starty,endx,endy); // here you can drawRect as per your value
    }
 }
}
```

check [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JPanelpaintComponentGraphicsg.htm) site

you need to pass the co-ordinate to the MainPanel class so you can draw the shape whatever you want to draw on panel.